# how to scroll two horizontal scrollviews side by side if i scroll any recycleview both will work like single recyclervie

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

please give me solution how to scroll two horizont recyclerviews side by side how to scroll two horizontal scrollviews side by side if i scroll any recycleview both will work like single recyclervie

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/nested"
                android:background="@color/Ashh"
  android:fillViewport="true"
            android:measureAllChildren="true"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">
                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/serverlist"
                    android:background="@color/Ashh"
                    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/locallist"
                    android:background="@color/Ashh"
                        android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
                    app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can try is

add on scroll listener to both of the recyclerviews

inside each get scroll position of recyclerview and set it to the others scroll position

Answer (score 0):

Code implementation of above answer:

```
your_recycler_view_1.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
   
        your_recycler_view_2.scrollToPosition(newState);
    }
});

your_recycler_view_2.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
   
            your_recycler_view_1.scrollToPosition(newState);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 <HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/nested"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_margin"
      />
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView

            android:id="@+id/recycler_view2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="@dimen/item_margin"
         />

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**TestActivity.java**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

public class TestActivity extends Activity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    RecyclerView recycler_view2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view2);

    
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(25,this));

    
    recycler_view2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    recycler_view2.setAdapter(new TestAdapter(25,this));

  }
}
```

Result

[image]

Comment: i dont want like that recyclerviews side by side horizontaly

Comment: what you expect share more